# Lightning in three.js

Tags: three.js

I just discovered this piece of code, which produces a nice Halo effect:
[Shader-Halo](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Halo.html)

I'm planning to remove the texture, and replace the SphereGeometry to a pipe or a line or something which will then act as a part of the lightning (I planing to chain a couple of glowing pipes/lines to appear as a lightning.)

So my question is: how to change this part in the code to draw a pipe/line instead of a sphere:

```
var ballGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 120, 32, 16 );
var ball = new THREE.Mesh( ballGeometry, customMaterial );
scene.add( ball );
```

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/CylinderGeometry

Comment: Sure, it's working, but not glowing like the sphere. 
Perhaps I should rewrite the shaders also? How to rewrite the shaders to make the Cylinder glow?

Comment: have you seen [this plasma ball](http://inear.se/plasmaball/)?

Comment: Hmm, looks very nice. Will analyse its code! Thank you for this. Perhaps this will be the solution.